# Swing : JScrollPane doesn't refresh after changes in the structure of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a JTable, associated with a DefaultTableModel, in a JPanel with a SpringLayout which is in a JScrollPane.

When I modify the structure of the DefaultTableModel with the method below the JTable is refreshed but not the JScrollPane. I have to apply a second time this method to refresh the JScrollPane.

```
public void updateProjectView() {
    SwingProjectViewerController spvc = SwingProjectViewerController.
            getInstance();
    this.projectTitle.setText(spvc.getAcronym() + " : " + spvc.getTitle());
    Object[][] tableContent =
            spvc.getCriteria(CriteriaPreselectionController.getInstance().
            getCriteriaPreselection());
    Object[] columnsName = new Object[]{"Col1", "Col2"};
    this.tableModel.setDataVector(tableContent, columnsName);
    this.tableModel.fireTableStructureChanged();
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: please 1) you didn't see updates into `JScrollPane` ???, 2) but how can you determine that `below the JTable is refreshed`

Comment: Have you tried calling `revalidate()` and perhaps `repaint()` on the JScrollPane's viewport? If this doesn't help, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: 1) For example my JTable contains a 2*15 table, the size of the table is bigger than the size of the container panel so there is a scrollbar on my JScrollPane. After I update the DefaultTableModel with a 2*3 table, and I see the changes in the JTable which is now smaller than the container panel. So the scrollbar should disappear but it doesn't. It disappear when I apply the method a second time.

Comment: further describing the problem doesn't make sense (it should behave as you expect without doing anything special besides setting the dataVector, no external event firing, no in/revalidating of any component) Time for an SSCCE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a test program that shows that when a JTable is held by a JScrollPane and the DefaultTableModel's DataVector is changed via `setDataVector(...)` it is not necessary to call  `fireTableDataChanged()` on the model for the JTable's data to change correctly and be viewed correctly.

The program GUI looks like the images below.
Before Data Changed:
[image]

After Data Changed:
[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ScrollPaneRefresh extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 200;
   private Integer[][] initialData = {
         {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 0},
         {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 0},
         {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 0}
         };
   private Integer[][] newData = {
         {1, 2}, {3, 4}
         };
   private String[] columnNames = {"Col1", "Col2"};
   private TablePanel gregsPanel = new TablePanel("With fireTableDataChanged", initialData, columnNames);
   private TablePanel myPanel = new TablePanel("Without fireTableDataChanged", initialData, columnNames);

   public ScrollPaneRefresh() {
      gregsPanel.setButtonAction(new AbstractAction("Change Table Data") {
         private boolean changeToNewData = true;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (changeToNewData) {
               gregsPanel.setTableModelDataVector(newData, columnNames);
            } else {
               gregsPanel.setTableModelDataVector(initialData, columnNames);
            }
            gregsPanel.fireTableDataChanged();
            changeToNewData = !changeToNewData;
         }
      });
      myPanel.setButtonAction(new AbstractAction("Change Table Data") {
         private boolean changeToNewData = true;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (changeToNewData) {
               myPanel.setTableModelDataVector(newData, columnNames);
            } else {
               myPanel.setTableModelDataVector(initialData, columnNames);
            }
            // myPanel.getScrollPane().getViewport().revalidate();
            changeToNewData = !changeToNewData;
         }
      });

      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
      add(gregsPanel.getMainPanel());
      add(myPanel.getMainPanel());
   }

   @Override // so scrollbars will show
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ScrollPaneRefresh mainPanel = new ScrollPaneRefresh();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollPaneRefresh");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class TablePanel {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private DefaultTableModel dm;
   private JTable table = new JTable();
   private JButton changeTableBtn = new JButton();
   private JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

   public TablePanel(String title, Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
      dm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
      table.setModel(dm);
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(changeTableBtn);

      mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
      mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      mainPanel.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      mainPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   public void setButtonAction(Action action) {
      changeTableBtn.setAction(action);
   }

   public void setTableModelDataVector(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
      dm.setDataVector(data, columnNames);
   }

   public void fireTableDataChanged() {
      dm.fireTableDataChanged();
   }

   public JScrollPane getScrollPane() {
      return scrollpane;
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }
}
```

The deficiency of my example above is that it does not reproduce the original poster's problem, and I think that is due to us use of SpringLayout, which he does not fully describe or show code:

> I have a JTable, associated with a DefaultTableModel, in a JPanel with a SpringLayout which is in a JScrollPane.

For more and better help, the OP is going to have to create his own [sscce](http://sscce.org) similar (or simpler) than what I've posted above. Either that, or solve his problem by not using SpringLayout to hold the JTable but rather either add it directly to the JScrollPane's viewport view or add it to a BorderLayout using JPanel (taking care to also add the JTable's header) and add that to the JScrollPane's viewport view.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. My problem comes from the use of the SpringLayout and using the BorderLayout solve the problem.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I didn't saw this answer +1

Comment: Worked for me with a similar issue. For other users that don't have this specific issue, try to restructure your class to allow to to you the relative 'setModel()' method. Personally I was using JXTreeTable, and it took me a while to find setTreeTableModel(), expecting setModel() to have been overwritten by the JXTreeTable class.

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this problem before.

Try invalidating the JTable and repainting the JScrollPane.

```
table.invalidate();
scrollPane.repaint();
```

Comment: would make me very nervous if random in/re/validates and/or repaints seem to fix a problem ;-) Something's wrong somewhere ...

Comment: @kleopatra: These calls aren't random.  They're specific to what I think the OP is doing.  Normally, you repaint a Swing component that you change.  Since JScrollPane is a container component, when you change the JTable, you have to repaint the container.

Comment: _Normally, you repaint a Swing component that you change_ no, not at all. Normally the component repaints/revalidates itself on changes. If that doesn't happen automatically, something is wrong - either in client code or in core. Whereever it is, it needs a proper track down instead of painting over ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try invoking revalidate() method on table. According to specification of JScrollPanel http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#update - "Dynamically changing client size" this method should notify Scroll Panel.

```
table.revalidate();
```